# How do you get information on the transaction status in braintree asynchonously?

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

So when I submit a braintree order for settlement, there will/can be multiple state changes until I get my money. It can settle, stay in settling, get declined, and so on.

How can I get this information without having to call their API constantly? Is there some kind of webhook for that? Because in my tests, I only get updates for disbursements, which is (if I understood it correctly) basically the last step of the whole transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/webhooks/overview)         for some events, but not for specifically when a transaction changes status.

You can, however, use the Search API to create a script or cron job that checks for [status changes over a period of time](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/transaction/search#status-changes).

If you have additional questions about webhooks or using the API, [contact Support](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help).

Comment: This is not an answer. I do know about webhooks in general, but I do not know about a specific webhook which solves my problem. Do you?

Comment: Sorry, mis-interpreted your question. Will update the answer